# change font of any particular column in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, font

I have shapefile with table having 10 columns. How to change font of only 1 particular column in arcgis 10.1 or any other software. For example if the table is having Calibri font for all 10 columns, I want to keep Calibri font in 9 columns and Arial in 1 column.

Comment: Is this when you view an Open Attribute Table or something else?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

In the Shapefile itself it is not possible to save any layout values, as it does not have these options.

With ArcGIS it is not possible to change the look of a single column or value, it is always for the whole table.

In QGIS you can do a bit in that direction by using conditional formatting. There you could take other fonts or colors for different values, but also no fontsizes for each column.

As it sounds like a pure design question it is maybe better to go for a spread sheet program like Excel or LibreOffice.